# What is the best way to store history of state and payout as a list in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with my list that store history.

Basically i have matrix of cells, and each cell got state, payout, and history. The history is an object that contain veriables `char state` and `double payout`, but i have a lot of problems with refferences. While i am trying to copy whole history, there is creating some reference that i dont know how to handle.

Let me show you the code (i know the copying way with two objects as a cells is stupid, but i was trying every possible way to get rid of those references):

```
public class Cell {

    public char state;
    public double payout;
    
    public class History{

        public char state='E';
        public double result;
        
        public History (char state, double result)
        {
            this.state=state;
            this.result=result;
        }
        public History (History history)
        {
            this.state=history.state;
            this.result=history.result;
        }
        public char getState()
        {
            return state;
        }
        public double getResult()
        {
            return result;
        }
    }


    public LinkedList<History> history;

    public Cell (Settings settings)
    {
        this.state=settings.state;
        this.payout=0;
        history= new LinkedList<History>();
    }
    public void copyCell ( Cell dest, Cell temp)
    {
        dest.state=temp.state;
        dest.payout=temp.payout;
        
        dest.history= new LinkedList<History>();
        
        for (int i =0; i<temp.history.size(); i++)
        {
            double result1=temp.history.get(i).result;
            char state1=temp.history.get(i).state;
            
            dest.history.add(new History (state1,result1));
        }
    }
}
```

What im doing wrong? I think i dont know the difference between copying veriables and making reference to the object. Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: And the problem is what exactly?

Comment: Post your Settings class.

Comment: how do you initiate the Cell dest that you pass to the copy method?

Comment: @akortex91 The problem is that after deleting history of one cell then few other histories are deleting also. Reference to the object that doesnt contain the right history is disappearing after deletion

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [momento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) pattern. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-memento-design-pattern) is a good tutorial to learn how to implement it as well as what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to best way storing history payout I would do following:

You need 3 components - `time`, `state` and `result` amount.

1. Time is required so you could sort the history the way you like and could load it per specified order from the db.
2. I would use linkedlist as it keeps the insertion order
3. Clone the history is easy just by clone the entire list
   `List<History> cloned = new LinkedList<>(oldList);`

Comment: After copying this way (3rd point), cells still have references to the copied cell. You think that using `List<History> cloned = new LinkedList<>(oldList);` we are creating new object without any references to the previous object?